# How to send APDU's via SMS to a java card applet?

Tags: javacard, globalplatform

I want to perform RMI , to an applet via SMS. My applet will process an APDU sent via the SMS and it will call a method depending on the APDU. I cannot find a method to achieve this.As per my reserch this depends on the card manufacturer and is not supported by all OS's. Is there any framework or technique which can help us to achieve the required result ?

Answer (score 1):

@Abhirup Ghosh: This is possible, search for NowSMS and Open Kannel.
Using these tools and GSM Modem, i have created utility that sends SMS to JAVACARD applet which processes the sms and gets the APDU in it.

You have to change your SMS Class and TYPE so that the OS of card treat it as envelope and pass it to the JAVACARD application.

You can also refer this paper:
http://www.ijsrp.org/research-paper-0415/ijsrp-p4024.pdf